# Cor do link do menu altera quando o scroll estiver sobre a sua respectiva seção

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, pessoal!

Qual código em JavaScript devo inserir para que, quando o usuário estiver navegando (dando scroll) sobre alguma seção o "li a" receba uma nova classe para que a cor do link seja alterada?

O ideal é que a seção "#inicio" receba a classe por padrão e que esse código funcione para os dois menus (#menu-mobile e #menu-desktop).

```css
#menu-mobile li a, #menu-desktop li a {
  color: #666666;
  }
```

```html
<header>

  <ul id="menu-mobile">
    <li><a href="#inicio" class="scroll inicio">página inicial</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#atuacao" class="scroll atuacao">área de atuação</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll portfolio">nosso portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contato" class="scroll contato">entre em contato</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="menu-desktop">
    <li><a href="#inicio" class="scroll">página inicial</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#atuacao" class="scroll">área de atuação</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">nosso portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contato" class="scroll">entre em contato</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  </header
```

Comment: você quer que quando o usuário passe o mouse por cima do link ele mude de cor?

Comment: Não, @Giovane . Gostaria que quando ele estivesse navegando e lendo algo da seção #contato (por exemplo), o link "Contato" do menu, ficasse com outra cor.

Comment: Entendi, você esta procurando um componente chamado ScrollSpy

Comment: Exatamente! Mas como ainda não aprendi js, tô me batendo pra aplicar esse código.

Comment: Olá. Removi a tag e a menção à UX, porque a sua pergunta independe disso. Pode ser mesmo que melhore (ou não) a UX, mas a pergunta continua sendo útil em escopo geral. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma olhada na documentação do [W3schools sobre o ScrollSpy do Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp).

Você basicamente vai importar os scripts necessários do jquery e do bootstrap e definir um estilo para o foco através da classe `active` que o scroll spy do bootstrap insere no elemento.

Veja:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#menu-desktop" data-offset="50">
  <header>
    <ul id="menu-desktop">
      <li><a href="#inicio" class="scroll">página inicial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#atuacao" class="scroll">área de atuação</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">nosso portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contato" class="scroll">entre em contato</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div id="inicio"></div>
  <div id="atuacao"></div>
  <div id="portfolio"></div>
  <div id="contato"></div>
</body>
```

Colocando `data-spy="scroll"` da tag body vai ativar o scrollspy.

O `data-target="#menu-desktop"` diz que o scrollspy faz referencia ao elemento com o id `menu-desktop`.

O `data-offset="50"` diz que ele deve começar a analizar o scroll apartir de 50px de distância do topo da tela.

Ai ele vai setar uma classe 'active' no `<li>` correspondente ao elemento que ele esta por cima.

Exemplo:

Com o foco na `<div id="inicio">` o `<li>` do link referenciando o id inicio vai receber o `active`, ou seja `<li class="active"><a href="#inicio">Ínicio</a></li>`.

É só definir um estilo de destaque quando a classe `active` for atribuída ao elemento de foco.

Comment: Obrigado, @Giovane !

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que a forma mais assertiva de você fazer isso é usando o seletor [:houver](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) do css. Algo assim:

```
#menu-mobile:houver{
    background-colo: white;
    color: red;
}
```

Você poderá também verificar a posição do scroll e alterar via JQuery, porém essa solução menos elegante e menos assertiva, levando em consideração se você estiver desenvolvendo pensando em design responsivo:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( scroll == 100 ) // 100 é valor simbolico da posicao do scroll com relacao ao topo
        $("#menu-mobile").addClass("alteraCor");
});
```

Essa é a documentação do [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) do JQuery.

Uma útima opção, para delimitar uma área mais abrangente para mudar de cor, é cincurdar os elementos que você quer mudar de cor por uma `div` e fazer ela cobrir uma área específica, quero dizer, ela ocupar uma linha toda e possuir determinado tamanho.

Comment: Não cara, isso é uma gambis feia. A melhor solução é ele usar um ScrollSpy